# How to test GCM client side on an AVD?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Good morning!

I'm trying to test `GCM` on an Android emulator but I keep getting a `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error.

I know my code is fine as I've already tested on an actual device and all worked well. My server-side code is in `C#.net`.

The Google documentation says the following:

`To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:`

`-A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.`

`-The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.`

My AVD is running `Android 4.4.2` and should be suitable for testing.

I'm not sure what the problem is, apparently `Google Play` cannot be installed on an emulator, so if the fact that it's missing is causing the issue then I guess I just can't test on an emulator (the docs say I can).

Has anyone successfully tested `GCM` on an Android emulator? And if so, how did you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do to make it work:

1. Follow google cloud messages step guide carefully
2. in AVD properties set target to Google API version 19 (you might need to install it using SDK manager)
3. Set cpu to ARM
4. if you're on windows then make sure that google play services lib and ADT workspace are on the same drive

It appears that x86 version of Google API v19 has an old version of GCM so it won't work